# Inserting item into list causes item to be deleted

Tags: vb.net, list, insert, resize

I currently am trying to insert a score into its proper position.  The scores add to their proper position.
However when I add or insert to the contained list it does not expand past its deserialized size.  (Note this highscore class is serialized to XML after the AddNewScore function is called.  Also it is deserialized when the program is loaded)

The issue only occurs after deserialization.

Here is my serialization code (its contained in a serialization class that manages saving and loading all data types I use)

```
Public Sub LoadHighScores()
        _highScores = DirectCast(LoadXml(highScoreFilePath, highScoreBackupFilePath, _highScoreFileCorrupted, GetType(HighScores)), HighScores)
        If (_highScores.scores.Count < 5) Then
            _highScores.AddNewScore(New Score("Steve", 9000))
            _highScores.AddNewScore(New Score("John", 8000))
            _highScores.AddNewScore(New Score("Paul", 7000))
            _highScores.AddNewScore(New Score("Alex", 6000))
            _highScores.AddNewScore(New Score("Joe", 5000))
            SaveHighScores()
        End If
    End Sub


 Private Sub SaveHighScores()
        If (File.Exists(highScoreFilePath) And Not _highScoreFileCorrupted) Then
            File.Copy(highScoreFilePath, highScoreBackupFilePath, True) 'Backup quiz data
        End If
        Using FileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(highScoreFilePath, FileMode.Create)
            'Dim encryptionStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(FileStream, AESCrypto.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(HighScores))
            serializer.Serialize(FileStream, _highScores)
            _highScoreFileCorrupted = False
            'encryptionStream.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

 Public Function LoadXml(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal backupFilePath As String, ByRef fileCorrupt As Boolean, ByVal dataType As Type) As Object
        Dim returnValue As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(dataType)
        If (File.Exists(filePath) Or File.Exists(backupFilePath)) Then
            Using fileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Using backupFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(backupFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(dataType)
                    Try
                        returnValue = serializer.Deserialize(fileStream)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        fileCorrupt = True
                        Try
                            returnValue = serializer.Deserialize(backupFileStream)
                        Catch e As Exception
                            MessageBox.Show("Backup Corrupted", "Loading error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                        End Try
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
        Return returnValue
    End Function
```

Here is my high score class

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Xml

Public Class HighScores
    Public scores As List(Of Score) = New List(Of Score)
    Public userplays As List(Of UserGameLog) = New List(Of UserGameLog)
    'Public userPlays As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdatePlays(ByVal Username As String)
        For Each userlog As UserGameLog In userplays
            If (userlog.username = Username) Then
                userlog.numberOfPlays += 1
                Return
            End If
        Next
        userplays.Add(New UserGameLog(Username))
    End Sub

    Public Function GetNumberOfPlays(ByVal Username As String) As Integer
        For Each userlog As UserGameLog In userplays
            If (userlog.username = Username) Then
                Return userlog.numberOfPlays
            End If
        Next
        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function GetHighScores() As List(Of Score)
        Return scores
    End Function

    Public Sub AddNewScore(ByVal score As Score)
        UpdatePlays(score.username)
        If (scores.Count > 0) Then
            For index = 0 To scores.Count - 1
                If (scores(index).score < score.score) Then
                    scores.Insert(index, score)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next

        End If
        scores.Add(score)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue, on loading the highscore list i was pulling out the 5 highest scores.  Instead of using range of I was assigning a new list the score list and removing the unused values to trim it down to 5 with

```
Public Function GetHighScores(ByVal maxScoreCount As Integer) As List(Of Score)
        Dim scores As List(Of Score) = New List(Of Score)
        scores = _highScores.scores
        If (scores.Count > maxScoreCount) Then
            scores.RemoveRange(maxScoreCount - 1, scores.Count - maxScoreCount)
        End If
        Return scores
    End Function
```

This was a reference to the prior list and it was cutting out my values.  Swapped it out with GetRange and problem is fixed.   *smacks head*